# .NET Core: Separate .exe from other libraries when publishing self-contained apps

Tags: .net-core

When you publish a .NET Core self-contained app right now, your exe is in the middle of a few dozen .NET Core runtime libraries, along with all the Nuget packages.

```
MyApp/
--ct/
--de/
--es/
...
--zh-Hant/
--Accessibility.dll
--api-ms-win-core-console.dll
... A dozen other .dlls
--MyApp.dll
--MyApp.exe
... Even more .dlls
```

I would like to set up publish so that these files are organized, like such

```
MyApp/
--netcoreapp3.0/
--nuget/
--MyApp.dll
--MyApp.exe
```

or even

```
MyApp.exe
MyApp/
--netcoreapp3.0/
--nuget/
--MyApp.dll
```

Alternatively, maybe there could be a way to change the directory of framework libraries in the .csproj `<TargetFramework>` tag? That way, I could use the framework-dependent publishing option and remove all the duplicate files.

Comment: Unless Microsoft changes its .NET Core SDK, you won't get what you wanted. If you really want some discussion on the details, talk to Microsoft via GitHub, https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues

Answer (score 1):

If there is no constraint to use the framework-dependent publishing option you can publish with the `PublishSingleFile` option being `true`.

Your publish command would be

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

Then in your publish folder you will find a "cleaner" result of an executable file, and some configuration files only (like appsettings.json or web.config). ***No nuget or runtime dlls.***

Comment: While this works, it's the nuclear option. I'd love to somehow have MSBuild compile the M$ and *nix libraries into a single .dll file while allowing my nuget libraries and other project library's to remain as separate dll.s